# sql and web encoding problem

Tags: mysql, php, encoding, utf-8

Guys, I've got an encoding problem I believe.

I have upgraded from phpBB2 to phpBB3.

The old databases were in latin1, the new ones have utf8 encoding.

Already during the upgrade process some rows of the DB were only read partly into the new version, because of strange characters as it turned out.

When I use PHP's mb_convert_encoding() function to convert those strings to UTF8 they end up e.g. as 0x0093, i.e. they must have been some kind of double quotes.

Even after doing this conversion, they still show up as 0x0093 in the browser (the squares with 0093 in them when the browser does not know what to display).

Can someone explain the problem here?

I'm a little confused and afraid I don't see all the dependencies that need to work to have the correct encodings and the correct display thereof...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the collation set in PHPBB and in database collation are the same. Double check all tables and rows for the data you are having problems.  I've ran into this before but don't have my notes handy.

Also, check in apache config uncommenting

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

may help.